# Open Multiple Unity Apps into Multiple Monitors

Tags: unity-game-engine, command-line, adapter, fullscreen, multiple-monitors

How do I open my Unity app, two single instances, into two different monitors full-screen (one in each monitor)?

Using this link https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html I have found that according to Unity all I have to do to open my Unity application multiple times into two separate monitors I use the -adapter N command. I have tried this and it always loads into the Main Display monitor. Here is my commands to open the application twice into separate monitors:

> start CCC.exe -force-d3d9 -adapter 1
>   start CCC.exe -force-d3d9 -adapter 2

I noticed in another article that only the d3d9 option works when using the -adapter option. Also, I'm using a NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 1070 with 8GB GDDR5 with Dual monitors plugged in 2 of the HDMI adapter ports.

Has anyone got this working? Much appreciated!

**Drew**

Comment: interesting, I can't help but, what is your project about if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: In my case, I have two different Unity installed, one for Hololens and one for regular. I have two icons and  I can open both at the same time as they are different applications. Maybe that'll help.

Comment: Have you tried holding shift when you launch the app and in the launch configuration window, choosing the display to use?

Comment: Were you able to test my answer below? Was it helpful?

Answer (score 2):

[Apparently](http://answers.unity3d.com/comments/536004/view.html) if you use Extended displays on Windows they both act as the same adapter, not sure what the intended use of the `adapter` switch is.

Alternatively, you could try an external solution. Create a program (.net for instance) that launches both instances and then moves one of them to the other monitor. Check this [guide](http://www.devasp.net/net/articles/display/689.html) to see how you can move a window from another program.

You probably want to use [borderless windowed mode](http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/363588/view.html) to show them fullscreen and still be able to move them to the desired position.

Ultimately, [here](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/30563)'s a paid solution that does all of this.